# Find misspelled documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Author document in my elasticsearch index. I have a user input to put new author in the index.

Before storing those new Author, I want to check if the Author already exist in the index, even if it was first misspelled.

I'm doing fuzzy search that seems to be the way of doing this.
Here is the request I'm doing:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/Author/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query":
  {
    "fuzzy": {
      "name": {
        "value": "put a name here"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Given I have an Author named "Daniel Bluefield".
The above request works well when I search "Danel".
But it don't return anythin if I search the full name, it did not return any result.

How can I make a request for "Danel Bluefld" returns some results ?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to fuzzy_like_this_field,you might need to tweak the [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-flt-field-query.html) parameter

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/Author/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query":
  {
    "fuzzy_like_this_field" : {
    "name" : {
        "like_text" : "Danel Bluefld",
        "max_query_terms" : 10
    }
   }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this request. I've also answered my ow question with a different query. Could you tell me the difference between our two answer ? The elasticsearch documentation really lacks details...

Answer (score 0):

The Mihai works well, however, I've managed to make it work another way:

```
{
  "min_score": 3,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "danil greenfld",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't really see the difference between those two queries...